# Windows update for Windows 98 and ME in a VM

Tags: virtualbox, windows-update, windows-98

I am running Win98, ME, W2K in Virtualbox VM's, windows update does not work for IE5 on any of them (page loop), I have managed to update them to IE6 and it continues to go into some sort of page loading loop, Is this a VM issue or just outdated browser/OS issue?

Does anyone know how to get Windows Update to work on these older versions of Windows?

Other update solutions welcomed also.

Edit, double checked W2K, it does not have a problem with Windows Update.

Comment: Interesting - I will check for you... I run Windows 2000 all the time from a VM - although I just use snapshots... I last installed it about a year ago. Installing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to [use this website](http://www.mdgx.com/) and download unofficial Update rollups for Win 98 and ME

Answer (score 3):

I have not been able to test Windows 98 or ME as I do not have a disk to hand.

However, I just tested Windows 2000 and on an out of the box setup (build 2195/SP4, Internet Explorer 5.00.3700.1000)), I was unable to reproduce any install loops you saw.

However, it did fail on error 0x800C0002.

This error I believe is due to the age of the Operating System and the fact that many of the out of the box certificates have expired and are no longer working... or/and, Microsoft have simply disabled the update servers.

I even manually downloaded the update rollup, which installed fine - but, it doesn't fix this issue.

So, sorry, no solution and my guess is that the update feature no longer works - and, if it doesn't work on Windows 2000, I highly doubt they would keep it active for ME or 98.

I would advise hunting the rollup updates, such as [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/891861) for Windows 2000.

(Error [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwjSl4bUSNQ))

Answer (score 0):

You might try [WindizUpdate](http://windizupdate.com/), the free alternative to Windows Update, that allows downloading all updates for a Microsoft OS as one update pack.

It is said to go quite a long way back, but I have no way to test for all the versions you mentioned. A quick google for example got me its [Security related patches for Windows 98 Gold](http://windizupdate.com/v2splist.php?id=-179068753).